# How to send Datagridview Values to Main form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I would like to send my Datagridview values to my Combobox in my mainform.

This is my code in my Datagridview form :

```
private void EquipmentList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable.RowCount = 30;

    //Beam Description default value
    DataTable.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = "8.000m x 0.400m x 0.550m";
}
```

Below code is what i've used but nothing happened :

```
        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.KeyPreview = true;


        EquipmentList ELform = new EquipmentList();

        //Beam Combo Box default values
        var BCBi1 = ELform.DataTable.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();


        this.BeamCB.Items.Add(BCBi1);


    }
```

When i run it i'm getting this error:

[error when running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZK9k.png)

An advance thank you for all those who will help me.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've done. Have you clicked the dropdown to check if the entry is in there. The first element will remain empty.

Comment: @Wheels73 it crashes. I have updated the above question and put a picture showing it crashes when i run it. Also i did tweak my code a bit but still nothing happened.

Comment: Which line does the exception throw? Have you actually added any columns and rows to your datagrid before you assign your value to the cell?

Comment: You have a `DataTable`called `DataTable`? What exactly _is_ `DataTable`?

Comment: DataTable is the name of my datagridview and it's located from another form (called "EquipmentList"). I want to send my default values (datagrid values) to my mainform.

Comment: Have you checked for the accessibility of the gridview `DataTable`.

Comment: @FreekW. yes my modifier is in public

Comment: OK. Then instead of `ELform.DataTable` try `((DataGridView)ELform.Controls["DataTable"])....`

Comment: And `EquipmentList_Load` is ran before running `MainForm_Load`. If not check that it does, if so check to see if the `EquipmentList` (or ELform in short) form is still active (that it's not closed at the time of running `MainForm_Load`.

Comment: @FreekW. Yeah i was suspecting that my Equipmentlist should run first. Because the values it contains runs only when i click/show my datagridview form. Am i right? So is there any possible to load that values wihtout clicking/showing my equipmentlist form.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Why don't you expose a public property on the combo box form and set it to the value you want from the grid before you show the form. I must say its not clear what you are trying to achieve? You are manually adding a string value to a grid cell and then referencing that grid value to add to a combo box?! perhaps say what the goal is and explain the interaction between for forms.

Comment: @LocEngineer i tried and i get this " this.BeamCB.Items.Add(BCDi1); "   BCDi1 has red underline.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @LocEngineer please see attached link for your ref https://imgur.com/a/V296n

Answer (score 1):

`DataTable.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value` is assigned in EquipmentList  form when it is loaded.

`EquipmentList ELform = new EquipmentList();` - here form is created but not loaded (you need to invoke `Show` or `ShowDialog` for that).

I suggest to declare publicly accessible default value (and not rely on existance of `DataTable` object with 1 row, which is a low-level implementation detail)

```
public const string DefaultSize = "8.000m x 0.400m x 0.550m";

private void EquipmentList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable.RowCount = 30;

    DataTable.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = DefaultSize;
}
```

and then

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.KeyPreview = true;

    this.BeamCB.Items.Add(EquipmentList.DefaultSize);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To the question "So is there any possible to load that values wihtout clicking/showing my equipmentlist form." Absolutely. Start by building a `class` for your data:

```
public class gridviewdata
{
   public string content { get; set; }
   public int row { get; set; }
   public int cell { get; set; }

   public gridviewdata(string content, int row, int cell)
   {
       this.content = content;
       this.row = row;
       this.cell = cell;
   }
}
```

add a mediator class:

```
public static class mediator
{
   public static List<gridviewdata> gridviewdatalist;
}
```

then add this code to your `ELform` load event:

```
private void EquipmentList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable.RowCount = 30;
    //Beam Description default value
    DataTable.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = "8.000m x 0.400m x 0.550m";
    mediator.gridviewdatalist.Add(new gridviewdata("8.000m x 0.400m x 0.550m", 0, 1);

}
```

then add a new method identifying your specific `row` to your `MainForm`:

```
private gridviewdata selectdata(int row, int cell)
{
   foreach(gridviewdata data in mediator.gridviewdatalist)
   {
      if(data.row == row && data.cell == cell)
       {
          return data;
       }
   }
   return null;
 }
```

And finally call that code in your `MainForm`:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.KeyPreview = true;

    //and call it there
    var BCBi1 = selectdata(0, 1);


    this.BeamCB.Items.Add(new Item(BCDi1, 1));    //Add value and index


}
```

Hope this helps.